# MongoDB find fields which are substring of a query text

Tags: mongodb

I have been looking for a way to do that but couldn't find any.

I'd like to know if is possible to, from a given query, return all fields that are contained in that query.

For example my dataset is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a072"), "id" : 0, "term" : "shorts" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a072"), "id" : 0, "term" : "jacket" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a072"), "id" : 1, "term" : "yellow jacket" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b56c1f74ace3a48a073"), "id" : 2, "term" : "blue jacket" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b65c1f74ace3a48a074"), "id" : 3, "term" : "blue shorts" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b71c1f74ace3a48a075"), "id" : 4, "term" : "red shorts" }
```

---

And now, given a text like: "I really love **blue shorts**", the return should be only:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b71c1f74ace3a48a075"), "id" : 3, "term" : "blue shorts" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a072"), "id" : 0, "term" : "shorts" }
```

It's something like query.contains(field)

Comment: If the ```term``` contains any word from the search-text, it should come in response?

Comment: No, it must be an exact matching between field and query text

Comment: Please elaborate how "I really love blue shorts" is an exact match for terms "blue shorts" and "shorts"?

Comment: By exact match I mean "blue shorts" and "shorts" are substrings from the query text "I really love blue shorts".

Answer (score 0):

> Using `$where` is generally discouraged in mongodb because of
>   javascript execution in the query system and can be slow.

You can try this out if the dataset is not very large. Its like doing reverse regex for the field value contained in the query.

```
db.collection.find({$where: "\""I really love blue shorts\".match(this.term)"});
```

Which outputs:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c32c1236f19364a8aad4d"), "id" : 0, "term" : "shorts"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c32c1236f19364a8aad51"), "id" : 3, "term" : "blue shorts"}
```

> NOTE: This takes the assumption that `term` is defined in the documents, else you can use a javascript function for the $where value to deal with edge cases such as not defined fields, etc.
>
> `{ $where: function() { return /* after edge cases dealt with*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "searchString":"I really love blue shorts"
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $gt:[
                    {
                        $indexOfBytes:["$searchString","$term"]
                    },
                    -1
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "searchString":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Data set:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a070"),
    "id" : 0,
    "term" : "shorts"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a071"),
    "id" : 0,
    "term" : "jacket"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a072"),
    "id" : 1,
    "term" : "yellow jacket"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b56c1f74ace3a48a073"),
    "id" : 2,
    "term" : "blue jacket"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b65c1f74ace3a48a074"),
    "id" : 3,
    "term" : "blue shorts"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b71c1f74ace3a48a075"),
    "id" : 4,
    "term" : "red shorts"
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b4cc1f74ace3a48a070"),
    "id" : 0,
    "term" : "shorts"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5c2b65c1f74ace3a48a074"),
    "id" : 3,
    "term" : "blue shorts"
}
```